# Writing streamed files into zip stream in java

Tags: java, zip, streaming, opencsv

I want to write `multiple CSVs` generated from different tables to a `zip` file without having a read/write operation required to store the generated `CSV` files or the generated `zip` files to a `memory`.

This `zip` I need to send as an output stream to a response. Is this possible to do in Java? If yes, then how? I am using `OpenCSV library` to generate `CSVs`.

Comment: is your application a servlet?

Comment: Please post some code of your application ([mcve])

Answer (score 0):

1. create a [GZIPOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html)
2. loop over your csv data units:

   - open an `InputStream` for the csv data unit
   - read it, write it to GZIPOutputStream
   - close `InputStream`
3. close `GZIPOutputStream`

If you are working with a servlet, you can wrap `ServletOutputStream` with `GZIPOutputStream`. If you like, I can give you more information on that.

Comment: Is this approach possible if the csv file is also generated on the fly? I am not reading the file from memory. Do you think that its possible? Because I think your solution assumes the CSV files to be read from memory.

Comment: yes I'mvery sure it's possible. By now, I'm not very familar with JAX-RS (but I have to learn it in a few days:-) ). I think it's possible to obtain an `OutputStream` (something derived) and combine it with `GZIPOutputStream`

Comment: I was struggling to generate `OutputStream` from `OpenCSV` api. If you know how to go about with that part, it would be helpful.